# Wrong type error when evaluating a function bound to key in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have written a function init-set-key-mappings that sets all the global keys in .emacs file.

```
(defun init-set-key-mappings ()
 "All the key mappings go here"
  (let ((mappings (list
                '("\C-ca"   'open-fileline))))
    (mapcar (lambda (mapping)
          (let ((key (car mapping))
                (func (cadr mapping)))
            (progn
              (message (format "map key %s to %s" key func))
              (global-set-key key func))))
        mappings)))
```

It evaluates fine, but when I press C-c a, Emacs complains "Wrong type argument commandp, (quote open-fileline)"

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I found the answer. Removing the quote before open-file seems to fix the problem. Why
is it being a symbol the problem? Isn't this how functions are passed around - as symbols?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You double-quoted the function `open-fileline`. In the expression

```
(list '("\C-ca" 'open-fileline)))
```

the first quote indicates that *everything* in the following list is quoted. You then added a *second* quote to `open-fileline`. Which means the list doesn't actually contain a symbol as the second element of it's car, but a *quoted* symbol. Compare:

```
(symbolp (cadar (list '("string" 'open-fileline))))
```

and

```
(symbolp (cadar (list '("string" open-fileline))))
```